# Python something wrong with "or"

Tags: python

So I faced new issue, maybe somebody could help? If I change nation to M, it doesn't work anymore. It should print "Thanks" if the nation is m or M.

```
nation = "m"
type = 1
if nation == ("m" or "M") and type == 1:
    print("Thanks")
```

Comment: `if nation.lower() == 'm' and type == 1:`

Answer (score 0):

```
nation = "m"
type = 1
if (nation == "m" or nation == "M") and type == 1:
    print("Thanks")
```